# System.Speech and Neural Networks

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am not sure where to post this. However, it's a general question. I program voice activated software, and I had a thought.

If I was to program a speech neural network. What options would be best to take?

I know that Aforge has machine learning with Fuzzy Logic. However, if I wanted to start from scratch.

I would be using back propagation, and possibly recursive learning. Would there be a way I could extract the default speech sound wave files that MS Speech uses, instead of recording every single word in the English language into a sound wave.

I have programmed feed forward and back propagation neural networks before.

My question is at this moment, is there a way to pull the sound wave files to implement the inputs, or will I need to record each word into a sound wave?

My long term goal is within the next 3 years is to have my program distinguish sentence structure, then the program would be able to piece together the nouns, verbs, adverbs, etc., etc.,. So it can create its own sentences to ask the user a question.

I don not want to use open source except for the sound waves. I can handle the coding. I just need to know if I can pull MS Speech sound waves or do I need to record them myself?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you have all the words you need.  Since the program is only speaking words (not recognizing the words) it doesn't matter.  The problem is if you have a mixture of words coming from two places it wouldn't make sense to have some words with German Accent and others with Italian Accent.  If the program was to listen to words that is a different story because you would need to have the program recognize lots of people speaking which would required a lot of samples of each word.

Comment: The program in the long run will be learning as I speak to it. So the system will listen to words as I speak. For example if I say "how much time do I have?" The system would take each word based on repetition and place them in a database. So adverbs to adverbs, and so forth. That's where the sound wav comes in.

Comment: The reason I was wondering about MS Wav is I am from the South East United States, I have a very strong southern drawl. So I don't want the system to recognize only one accent. I want it to be universal. At this point MS wav is my only option.

Comment: Are you doing "Speech Recognition" or just "Generating Sentences"?  Or both?  Creating a Sentence is different from Recognizing a Sentence.   Read you request again.  It is not clear.  You wrote : "So it can create its own sentences to ask the user a question".  Answer could be pressing buttons, typing answers or Speech Recognition.

Comment: I am doing Speech Recognition, Speech Synthesis and Sentence generation. Look at this way I a Speech Recognition Researcher. And I am also in the race of building an Un-Supervised Learning machine. So my idea is since the Neural Networks are mimicking the Human Brain. We have to learn the sentence structure in growing up in English class. So I am recreating 8th grade all over again. I am learning sentence structure with a Neural Network. So the Neural Network will be used for the system to learn like we did in 8th grade, 20 odd years ago.

Comment: I started working on one of the 1st Synthesis for the military.  Understand the process well.  You task has 3 parts 1) Sentence Structures 2) Speech Synthesis 3) Speech Recognition.  You question is really about #2,  Most Synthesizers use only one Voice for speaking,  The voice can sound mechanical or human.  Using Sound Waves will be more mechanical and easier to program.  You may want to attempt to make a synthesizer that learns voice sound from human inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural Language Processing (NLP) is a Text Based approach to Machine Comprehension. There are some very good papers that may give you a place to start:

https://openreview.net/pdf?id=B1-q5Pqxl

and

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09830v2.pdf

A MATCH-LSTM Neural Network Architecture seems to be the current state of the Art for as you say:

> My long term goal is within the next 3 years is to have my program
>   distinguish sentence structure, then the program would be able to
>   piece together the nouns, verbs, adverbs, etc., etc.,. So it can
>   create its own sentences to ask the user a question.

Some example code was published by Wang and Jiang : https://github.com/shuohangwang/SeqMatchSeq

Your goal is board, but I believe achievable. Massive milestones have been reached already. Good Luck!